# polymorphism java - doesn't go to a specific functions

Tags: java, polymorphism

While running I have byte [] as a body
But I'm still signing in to the (Object Entity) signature
If I make a cast to byte [] then I enter the second signature.

How can I make it work dynamic ?

```
public static <T> T makePostRequest(String request, Map<String, String> header, Object body, Class<T> myClass) {
    return makeRequest(request, header, "POST", myClass, con -> {
        if (body != null) setBody(con, body);
    });
}

private static void setBody(HttpURLConnection con, byte[] entity) throws IOException {
    setBodyHandler(con, wr -> wr.write(entity));
}

private static void setBody(HttpURLConnection con, Object entity) throws IOException {
    setBodyHandler(con, wr -> wr.writeBytes((new Gson()).toJson(entity).toString()));
}
```

But this does work, why?

```
public static <T> T makePostRequest(String request, Map<String, String> header, Object body, Class<T> myClass) {
    return makeRequest(request, header, "POST", myClass, con -> {
        if (body != null) setBody(con, (new Gson()).toJson(body).toString());
    });
}

public static <T> T makePostRequest(String request, Map<String, String> header, byte[] fileBytes, Class<T> myClass) {
    return makeRequest(request, header, "POST", myClass, con -> {
        if (fileBytes != null) { setBody(con, fileBytes); }
    });
}
```

Comment: overloading is not polymorphism

Comment: run time polymorpshism does not work with static method. There is nothing connected with plomorphism with static methods.

Comment: How do you call those functional function ? with an instance `byte[]` and an instance `Object` ? Since both function now used a specific type, the call of `fileBytes` is correct. Now, the way you call `makePostRequest` can still fail.

Comment: This has nothing to do with static or not static methods. This has everything to do with static vs dynamic dispatch. Java does have method **overloading** for static methods, just not dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @Lino: technically, overloading **is** a form of polymorphism :)

Comment: Yeah, this is about type overloading - two methods, same name: `foo(Type1 arg)` and `foo(Type2 arg)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have **dynamic dispatch** - it cannot match methods based on the **runtime** type of the object, only based on the **declared** (static) type of the object. Therefore, the method that will be called is always one that will correspond to the declared type of the variable (in your case, that's `Object` since that's the parameter's type) and not the closest runtime type (which is `byte[]`). Apart from using some sort of reflection (such as `instanceof` or `getClass()`) and conditional casts, there is really no way around this.

Comment: i edit the question, 
so why the second part does work ?

Comment: As I said, Java will differentiate based on your parameter type. In this case, since the parameter type is explicitly `byte[]`, it will call the appropriate method (but you still had to somehow call the right `makePostRequest` method, so you only moved your conundrum up a level).

Comment: Does it happen only in static functions?
@Piotr Wilkin

Comment: No, this happens everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do such dispatch at runtime. If you have just these two cases, this should work:

```
private static void setBody(HttpURLConnection con, Object entity) throws IOException {
    if (entity instanceof byte[]) {
        setBody(con, (byte[])entity);
    } else { 
        setBodyHandler(con, wr -> wr.writeBytes((new Gson()).toJson(entity).toString()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this first check what is the body is instance of byte[] else call the method with Object as an argument.

```
public static <T> T makePostRequest(String request, Map<String, String> header, Object body, Class<T> myClass) {
            return makeRequest(request, header, "POST", myClass, con -> {
                if (body != null) {
                    if(body instanceof byte[])
                       setBody(con, (byte[]) body);
                    else
                    {
                        setBody(con, body);
                    }
                }
            });
```